# Which Mosaic laws did Nehan foreigners (immigrants that were not proselytes) had to follow while staying in Israel (long or short term)

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, noachide-laws

I would like to know what Mosaic laws were non-proselyte residents in ancient Israel expected to keep?

I'll break that question for more clarity:

- Did the non-proselyte have to follow at least Noahide laws while staying in Israel, be it for their one-week stay or a decades stay or permanent stay?
- For example, what if the non-proselyte had idols of gods he worshipped in his home, was that allowed? If yes, then could groups of non-proselytes gather for their religious festivals of worshipping their gods as long as their worship did not require any sacrifice?
- As I understand that sacrificing anywhere outside the gates of tabernacle was not allowed.
- If a non proselyte wasn't a worker class was he expected to keep sabbath? Let's say if he owned a business or shop and he gave offs to his workers, but could he keep his shop/trade open for other non-convert foreigners?
- There were times God asked His people to sanctify themselves for His presence or I think for festivals too (I'm not sure on festival part), so let's say if a non-proselyte sojourner wanted to feast with everyone, they'd join the feast but were they to set themselves apart for eating sacrifices along with Israelites? I understand that they had to be circumcised if they wanted to participate in the Passover, which means they had to become a proselyte for that. I'm not talking about Passover but other festivals.

Thank you so much.

All help will be greatly appreciated. It'll be great if you can post verses supporting the answers.

I also realise there were two different types of sojourners. One who were proselytes and others who were not proselytes. I'm specifically asking about sojourners who were not proselytes.

Thanks & Much Regards

PS: you can also refere to my another thread for more insight on the same question:

[Which laws were for just Israelites and which laws for Israelites and non proselyte foreigners](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/130181/which-laws-were-for-just-israelites-and-which-laws-for-israelites-and-non-prosel)

Comment: Pretty sure non-proselyte foreigners were not allowed to stay long-term at all (assuming I understand your terms correctly, a "proselyte foreginer" would be a "ger toshav")

Comment: Assuming they had something like a 'Customs and Immigration', they would have to accept the 7 laws of Noach at the port of Entry. ( Rambam )

Comment: The sacrifices brought on the other holy days (such as Succos) could also not be brought by nonJews. If a person converted, then he was completely Jewish and was treated as a *citizen* in all respects. As such he was no longer a *sojourner* If he had not converted then he could only bring an animal for a burnt offering, not a regular sacrifice. He was also not allowed on the temple mount grounds.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!